# Is there a source for this anecdote about Chandragupta Maurya, battle strategies and hot rice?

Tags: india, ancient-india, strategy

An anecdote (1) about Chandragupta Maurya indicates he learnt that attacking margins is a better battle strategy than attacking the center, and that this insight came from a hot dish (possibly hot rice, may be a hot cake). I'm looking for a genuine reference for this anecdote, but I haven't been able to come up with any. I have found one possible reference for this anecdote (2), but this is inaccessible.

Does anyone know of a reputable (academic or folklore book) reference for this anecdote?

References:
(1) [issuu.com](https://issuu.com/daraniv93/docs/chanakya)
(2) [Kauṭilya and the Arthaśāstra](https://books.google.com/books?id=v3iDAAAAMAAJ)

Comment: I see the question had been downvoted. Could the downvoter explain why?

Comment: I didn't do it, but some possible issues I see that folks may have here is that a lot of our users don't like "I heard from a drunk in a bar once..." questions, and that there are no links or references provided for anything in this question. The first could be mitigated by finding a link to someone (anyone) saying this online. The second could be helped out with some links in general (the person in question's Wikipedia page, or some rough equivalent, would be a good start).

Comment: Also, if you could edit in some text about what you've already tried (and presumably failed at) to find more info on it, that's usually appreciated (and sometimes demanded). That keeps our users from wasting their time with research that you already know won't pan out.

Comment: @T.E.D. Thank you. I have edited the question with the (unreliable or inaccessible) references.